# Copy entire rows based on multiple cell values

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to copy entire rows where two values are blank and the third cell value is `MS-NORT`,
My code is below but I am getting a **syntax error**.

please help

```
Set MK = Sheets("data dump").Range("P1:Q5000")
For Each cell In MK

If cell.Value = "" And Sheets("Data Dump").Range("M1:M5000") <> "MS-NORT" 
Then cell.EntireRow.copy
Sheets("working data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
End If
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next
```

Comment: Syntax error in which line specificly?

Comment: If cell.Value = "" And Sheets("Data Dump").Range("M1:M5000") <> "MS-NORT"

Comment: Updated the answer, have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "where two values are blank and the third cell value is MS-NORT"

I've assumed you want to check each row and if column M <> "MS-NORT" and both columns P and Q are blank then copy the row. This code will do that

```
Sub test()
Dim rngRow As Range, MK As Range, lngrow As Long
Dim varCheckCol1 As Variant, varCheckCol2 As Variant, varCheckCol3 As Variant

Set MK = Sheets("data dump").Range("M1:Q5000")
For Each rngRow In MK.Rows

  varCheckCol1 = rngRow.Value2(1, 1) 'col M
  varCheckCol2 = rngRow.Value2(1, 4) 'col P
  varCheckCol3 = rngRow.Value2(1, 5) 'col Q

  If IsEmpty(varCheckCol2) And IsEmpty(varCheckCol3) And varCheckCol1 <> "MS-NORT" Then
     rngRow.EntireRow.Copy
     Sheets("working data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
  End If

Next

End Sub
```